# Access to SQL Server grant from any machine except server with database

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-string

In my job we have several servers with SQL Servers. Every one has several instances. Access to any was clear... until today. I wrote app in WPF which use connection string as this

```
Data Source=server02\system; Initial Catalog=*****; User Id=*****; Password=*****;
```

Under every * hides char [a-zA-Z], digit or special char.
When I run my app from my coputer location everything works, but if I run it from server02 location (//server02/apps/app.exe) it fails.

Exception:

```
SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 – Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
```

And the question is... How to fix it? Why the hell server connected to our LAN doesn't recognize his own localdb?!

Comment: Does `select @@SERVERNAME` executed on that server give you the same name, server02\system?

Comment: yeah, exactly .

Comment: Is the SQL Server Browser service running? What does `ping server02` yield from the local machine? Does it work if you specify `tcp:server02\system` for the data source?

Answer (score 0):

Enable `Named Pipes` connections from your SQL Server instance.

For this just go to `SQL Server Configuration Manager` to enable `Named Pipes`.

Comment: Done, but we need restart server to check this out. For now we can't, till tomorrow I will reply. Do You think it's just about enabling this option?

Comment: This could be a DNS problem also make sure the server can resolve `server02` too

Comment: @Hybris95 So you think it cannot resolve its own name? Or it uses named pipes instead of shared memory when connecting from the same pc?

Comment: Using shared memory can make it work also. Anyway this sounds more like a network issue than an SQL Server issue.

Comment: damn, turning it on didn't help. casual DNS settings like on another machines.